# How to use decimal type in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I store decimals in MongoDB using the standard C# driver? It seems that all decimals are stored inside the database as strings.

Comment: See blog post https://kevsoft.net/2020/07/02/how-to-store-decimal-fields-in-mongodb-with-csharp.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't properly support decimals until MongoDB v3.4. Before this version it stored decimals as strings to avoid precision errors.

**Pre v3.4**
Store decimals as strings, but this prevents arithmetic operations. Operators as `$min`, `$avg`, ... won't be available. If precision is not a big deal, then you might be able to switch to `double`.

**v3.4+**
You need to make sure the following preconditions are true:

- MongoDB server should be at least v3.4.
- MongoCSharpDriver should be at least v2.4.3.
- Database should have `featureCompatibilityVersion` set to `'3.4'`. If your database has been created by an older MongoDB version and you have upgraded your server to v3.4 your database might still be on an older version.

If you have all the properties set, then register the following serializers to use the `decimal128` type:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(decimal), new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(decimal?), new NullableSerializer<decimal>(new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128)));
```

Comment: Where do you put the BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer code in the project?

Comment: @stoneMaster I often use a static constructor for my Mongo-context. This works fine if you have a single Mongo context-class. Another option is not to provide a default registration, but to specify the serializer in the fluent configuration:
`r.MapProperty(_ => _.Value) .SetElementName("value") .SetIsRequired(true) .SetSerializer(new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128))`.

Answer (score 15):

I recently ran in to this problem. I solved it by simply annotating my object like this:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
public decimal Price {get; set;}
```

Comment: much more elegant to do it globally imo as I have many decimals and this should be the default behaviour

Answer (score 4):

I had issues using the `RegisterSerializer` approach as it complained that it already had a serializer registered, but an alternative is to write your own serialization provider and use that.

Here's the provider:

```
public class CustomSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    private static readonly DecimalSerializer DecimalSerializer = new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128);
    private static readonly NullableSerializer<decimal> NullableSerializer = new NullableSerializer<decimal>(new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128));

    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(decimal)) return DecimalSerializer;
        if (type == typeof(decimal?)) return NullableSerializer;

        return null; // falls back to Mongo defaults
    }
}
```

which you need to register by calling

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CustomSerializationProvider());
```

Comment: there's also the TryRegistrerSerializer() method that will not register it in case it was already registered.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like Erik Kindling, by annotating the object like this:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
public decimal Price {get; set;}
```

However, it is important that you re-populate your mongodb collection otherwise the string value will be preserved.
The field value will be in this format once inserted properly:

```
"Price" : NumberDecimal("99")
```

Comment: Just a small addition to your comment to make it clearer: "... otherwise the EXISTING string value will be preserved."