# Why doesn't MongoDB C# driver use BsonType.Decimal128 representation for decimals by default?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm surprised to see it uses string representation even if the type is `decimal`. I have to explicitly set representation to BsonType.Decimal128...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43473148/2828480

Is it for backwards compatiblity? https://kevsoft.net/2020/07/02/how-to-store-decimal-fields-in-mongodb-with-csharp.html

> I feel for most applications setting the DecimalSerializer globally with the representation of BsonType.Decimal128 is totally fine and should be the default, however, due to the legacy of MongoDB not supporting decimal from the start, I can see why it defaults to strings for backwards compatibility.

I will have nightmares tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2210

> Values of type System.Decimal are serialized as strings for two
> reasons:
>
> 1. The range of System.Decimal is different from that of BSON Decimal128 so overflow or loss of precision is possible
> 2. For backward compatibility (the driver has been serializing System.Decimal as string since before the BSON Decimal128 type was
>    introduced)
>
> If you want to configure your application to serialize System.Decimal
> as BSON Decimal128 you can do so by adding the following configuration
> code to your application:
>
> ```
> var decimalSerializer = new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128, new
> RepresentationConverter(allowOverflow: false, allowTruncation:
> false)); 
> BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(decimalSerializer);
> ```
>
> You must register this serializer as early as possible. At a minimum it
> must be registered before any System.Decimal values are serialized.

Comment: I'd appreciate more explanation > The range of System.Decimal is different from that of BSON Decimal128 so overflow or loss of precision is possible